# update System.Web.WebPages dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-assembly

I got the error CS1705:

> Assembly 'PagedList.Mvc, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abbb863e9397c5e1' uses 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' with a higher number of version than assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', wich is refferenced.

I want to update the System.Web.WebPages in order to get a correct reference of PagedList.MVC to System.Web.WebPages.
 (as displayed in the following link at the bottom of the page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/416tef0c.aspx )

Where I can find a download or something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use PagedList.Mvc in MVC 3, Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671081/cant-use-pagedlist-mvc-in-mvc-3-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use MVC3 the better solution for you will be to download more earliest version of [PagedList](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList/), because "`System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0`" is used by MVC4. MVC3 will generate an error if you change `Version=1.0.0.0` `to Version=2.0.0.0`.

The other solution is update your MVC3 project to MVC4. You may use [autoupdate tool from Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UpgradeMvc3ToMvc4) or there are a big nomber of articles in web, how to do it by hand.

Comment: You can use `Install-Package PagedList.Mvc -Version 3.18.0.0` to download an older version.

Comment: thanks a lot. worked really well. i tried the package manager control to force an install of PagedList with a lower number of version