# NuGet PagedList not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagedlist

I am using PagedList in MVC aspx application for pagination but while runtime  got error that

> does not contain a definition for Html.PagedListPager and no extension method

I have installed `PagedList.Mvc 4.5.0.0` and used  in aspx page  ,in controller included name space `PagedList` but when i am adding  `PagedList.Mvc` i got compile time error...

> Assembly 'PagedList.Mvc, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=abbb863e9397c5e1' uses 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

To resolve above error i have added `<add assembly="PagedList.Mvc" namespace="PagedList.Mvc" tagPrefix="plmvc"/>` in web.config  but no change.

Please Help

Comment: See [Can't use PagedList.Mvc in MVC 3, Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671081/cant-use-pagedlist-mvc-in-mvc-3-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools-->Nu-Get Package Manager-->Package Manager Console
Then a window will appear at the bottom of Visual studio.
Just type the command 
PM> Install-Package PagedList.Mvc -Version 3.18.0

The above command should be as it is any space added will not work.
Happy coding